# Simulate on Xcode 6 somethings wrong

Tags: ios-simulator, ios8, device, xcode6

I installed Xcode 6 gm version. I created new project and I run it on iPhone 6 or iPhone 5s simulator with ios 8. Everything is fine.But When I simulate on iphone 5s deployment target ios 7.1.Device screen is not full screen.it runs like as 3.5inc screen.Do you know reason of that? Is it XCode 6's bug?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put launch screen for iphone 5 - 640x1136 named Default-568h@2x or use catalog assets alternatively.

Comment: Is there a way to skip that behavior? I faced the same issue however I don't need launch screen. Xcode 6 beta didn't produce such issue

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a solution in my case

1. Go to **General** tab of project's target
2. Scroll down to **App Icons and Launch Screens** section
3. Click on **Use Asset Catalog** drop down option under **Launch Images Source**
4. In prompt choose **Migrate** - this will create **LaunchImage** category under .xcassets image set (default Images.xcassets in my case)
5. Launch the app - ifullscreen issue gone in my case

[image]